# Creating C# Class or Struct with behavior like Nullable

Tags: c#, class, struct, nullable, behavior

I'm trying to create a simple class or struct that behave like Nullable struct

Sample Code:

```
// This Class Behave like Nullable<int>
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
    }

    public void ProcessValue()
    {
        ... Body ...
    }

    public bool HasValue
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}

public static class Main
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SomeClass a = 20; //int Type
        a.ProcessValue();
    }
}
```

Can this is even posible? I'm try to search everywhere, but got no luck finding the answer. Or maybe I don't know what the search keywords is.

Can Somebody help me.

Thanks
A'an

Comment: What is the problem at hand? Note that you can mimic some, but not all functionality of `Nullable<T>`, since some of it is baked into the compiler.

Comment: Did you look at the actual implementation? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e. Or what exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you stuck at any **specific** point? Anyway: why re-invent the wheel? What speaks against `Nullable`?

Comment: Yes, it can be done, but you should *really* want that kind of behavior because you cannot turn it off (other than ripping out the support again), which means you can involuntarily get an int converted to your class. However, here's a one-liner for what you want: `public static implicit operator SomeClass(int a) => new SomeClass(a);` Add this inside your class.

Comment: Yes thanks [Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v%C3%A5gs%C3%A6ther-karlsen). Indeed I need to look [implicit and explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/conversion-keywords) operator from C# Reference.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just pass the value via the constructor...that you've declared for no real benefit? Seeing an `int` assigned to a class instance is an odd semantic; it's not something I expect to see when I look at someone's code. Furthermore, you're going to have extra instances of your class created whenever you (re)assign to the variable. (I actually wonder if this might lead to a memory leak somehow.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could implement the implicit cast operator to assign an integer to your type. But that seems to be a bad design. I would not recommend to do so.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. Thanks [Bettzueche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8674456/bettzueche).

Comment: No, that is not a correct answer. Why is that bad design? This should be a comment at most, and then it would be a bad one. @AanDahliansyah

Comment: In my opinion it is mostly bad design because it's confusing. What should that mean `SomeClass a = 20`? When I can assign integers, can I also add and multiply types of `SomeClass`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, Like Bettzueche say, I should read about implicit / explicit C# operator and that the correct answer. I'm designing socket communication libs. I think this is the best approach for my foundation class and not visible to public class. thx.